# Read static variable vs read from mongodb in multi threading performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb

I have a static dictionary as

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> dicRespCodes;
```

which is initialized in static constructor

```
static ApplicationHelper()
{
     dicRespCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     dicRespCodes = LoadResponseCodes();
}

public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadResponseCodes()
{
     Dictionary<string, string> dicRespCodes = new Dictionary<string,string();

     SqlParameter[] arr = { new SqlParameter("@GatewayCode", gatewayCode) };

     SqlCommand cmd = DbContext.CreateCommand(connAMS, "GetResponseCodes", arr);
     var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (dr.Read())
     {
         dicRespCodes.Add(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
     }

     return dicRespCodes;
}
```

This dictionary is being used in multi threaded environment.

My question is about the performance of static dictionary vs mongodb read on every thread.

The below method is using both approaches, which would be efficient in multi threading?

```
public string GetResponseDescription(string code)
{
    //mongodb = mongoClient.GetDatabase("ApplicationDB");
    //ResponseCodes col = mongodb.GetCollection<ResponseCodes>
    ("ResponseCodes").Find(Builders<ResponseCodes>.Filter.Eq("ResponseCode", 
    code)).FirstOrDefault();
    //return col.ResponseDescription;

    if (dicRespCodes.ContainsKey(code))
        return dicRespCodes[code];
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested both? I'd thoroughly *expect* the dictionary approach to be faster, although I'd use `TryGetValue` rather than effectively looking up the key twice. (There's also no reason to set `dicRespCodes` to a `new Dictionary<string, string>()` and then immediately assign it a new value. You might as well remove the static constructor and just initialize in the field declaration: `private static Dictionary<string, string> dicRespCodes = LoadResponseCodes();`

Comment: Having said which, using a global for this isn't idea IMO, nor is doing work like this in a static initializer. I'd consider having a regular class that you create an *instance* of. This is likely to make your code easier to test, aside from anything else.

Comment: Agreed with the TryGetValue point. The purpose of initializing dictionary in static constructor is that, it is initialized once on app startup.

Comment: but i want to know the performance in multi threading environment not for one thread

Comment: So test the performance in a multi-threading environment, in as realistic conditions as you can. That's something only you can do - we don't know what the usage is likely to be. I'd still strongly advise you to use an instance rather than a static constructor - you can then pass that instance around and share it everywhere, but you still end up with better testability.

Comment: `My question is about the performance of static dictionary vs mongodb read on every thread.` A local dictionary will **almost always** beat a mongodb read - mainly since you avoid any network hops.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not how to implement a thrad safe dictionary.

Use a `ConcurentDictionarry` instead, don't use static variables as much as possible.

For you question obviously a memory held data will be much faster accessed than a data located in a `mongodb` server.

One thing you shuold keep in mind is that you need to make sure your memory data is up to date with you database!(which is you single point of truth). so you must implemet a `TTL` logic to your memory! I suggest using the .NET `MemoryCache` object!

Comment: If the dictionary is only ever modified on construction, it's safe for concurrent *read* access.

Comment: The answer is for multithreaded environment, i dont understand you

Comment: So ConcurentDictionary would be preferable instead of reading from mongodb in multi threaded environment? Right!

Comment: can you please share some piece of code for global access.

Comment: search `ConcurentDictionarry` , its very simple

Comment: I searched for ConcurentDictionary and found it is slower than Dictionary with thread increases.

Comment: If `LoadResponseCodes` is the only place **writing** to the `Dictionary` then you should leave it as a `Dictionary` @AdnanNaseerShaikh. `I searched for ConcurentDictionary and found it is slower than Dictionary with thread increases.` `ConcurrentDictionary` is basically always slower than `Dictionary` - but for some scenarios (e.g. involving reads / writes that are multi-threaded with writes) then `Dictionary` **just doesn't work reliably** - so speaking about which is slower is irrelevant.